# getattr and unicode attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x

Since it has become possible to use unicode characters in identifiers for class, methods, variables, I use them more and more. I don't know, if this is A Good Idea, but it makes the code more readable (e.g. you can now use `import numpy as np; π = np.pi; area = r**2 * π`!)

Now I noticed the following behaviour (in Python 3.8.5):

I can define a class `A` the following way:

```py
>>> class A:
...     def x(self):
...         print('x')
...     def ξ(self):
...         print('ξ')
...     def yₓ(self):
...         print('yₓ')
```

and can access all methods:

```py
>>> a = A()
>>> a.x()
x
>>> a.ξ()
ξ
>>> a.yₓ()
yₓ
```

The problem arises, if I want to use `getattr()` to access them:

```py
>>> attr = getattr(a, 'x')
>>> attr()
x
>>> attr = getattr(a, 'ξ')
>>> attr()
ξ
>>> attr = getattr(a, 'yₓ')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'yₓ'

'A' object has no attribute 'yₓ'
```

1. Why does `getattr(a,'ξ')` work, but `getattr(a, 'yₓ')` does not?

I noticed

```py
>>> dir(a)
[…, 'x', 'yx', 'ξ']
```

2. Why is `'ξ'` kept, but `'yₓ'` silently converted to `'yx'`? Which are the "safe" characters, which can be used, so that `getattr()` succeeds?
3. Is there a way, so that I can use `yₓ`?

BTW, `yₓ` can be used, but `y₂` gives a `SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier`

4. Why can't I use `y₂` at all?

I know, the workaround is, to not use any of those fancy characters, but some of them make the code really more readable (at least in my view!) …

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identifier normalization: Why is the micro sign converted into the Greek letter mu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097193/identifier-normalization-why-is-the-micro-sign-converted-into-the-greek-letter)

Comment: As a general rule, ask yourself: "Is this character part of the native script for a non-English language?" If the answer is "no", tread carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-ASCII identifiers are defined in [PEP 3131](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3131/). In it, it says that:

> The entire UTF-8 string is passed to a function to normalize the string to NFKC

You can test this for yourself with [`unicodedata.normalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize):

```py
unicodedata.normalize("NFKC", 'ξ') # 'ξ'
unicodedata.normalize("NFKC", 'yₓ') # 'yx'
```

[NFKC is very complicated, but you should be able to find safe characters with a loop.](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/)

Comment: This answer together with the link provided by @green-cloak-guy in the question's comment (section)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65093243/getattr-and-unicode-attributes#comment-115079147] explains, what is going on: Python normalizes identifiers when parsing the script. Thus `.yₓ` actually becomes `.yx`, whereas `.ξ` stays `.ξ`. `getattr()` does not normalize the attribute string, resulting in this puzzling behaviour. Hence:
```python3
class A:
    def yₓ(self):
         return 'yₓ'
    def yx(self):
         return 'yyxx'
a = A()
a.yₓ()
```
prints `yyxx` and not `yₓ`.

Comment: I wonder, why Python normalizes the identifiers. Why doesn't it just use the unicode character(s) as identifier?